# Stripe Checkout does not work on WebView

Tags: android, ios, webview, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial) inside a WebView (both in Android and in iOS).
If I run the demo checkout in this [page](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial) from `Google Chrome` from mobile it opens a new web page and everything works fine.

When I try to run the demo from a WebView (which I expect to behave in a completely similar way) it does not work and gives me a

```
Sorry, there was a problem loading Checkout.
If this persists, please try a different browser.
```

I thought that it is not made for mobile, but this is not true because from Google Chrome works perfectly fine.
Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: Stripe Checkout doesn't support Webviews at all. You need to build your own payment form instead using Stripe.js: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js and https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms

Comment: I didn't completely understand this choice, why on a mobile Web browser like Google Chrome it is supported and on a simple webview it is not? Same screen, same height same width...

Comment: Because webviews are their own browser implementation it's not exactly Chrome or Firefox, etc. so Stripe does not support Webviews at all for Checkout. You should build your own payment form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I managed to work with [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial) on webviews (I used Xamarin):

1. Install [Plugin.Share](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin) from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Share/) (project, add newget packages both in shared and specific mobile project folders)
2. Try out this code to see that checkout works fine:

   ```
   using System;

   using Xamarin.Forms;
   using Plugin.Share;
   using Plugin.Share.Abstractions;

   namespace stripewebviewtest
   {
       public class App : Application
       {
           public App ()
           {
               Button btn = new Button ();
               btn.Text = "Click on me!";        

               // The root page of your application
               MainPage = new ContentPage {
                   Content = new StackLayout {
                       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                       Children = {
                           new Label {
                               XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                               Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                           },
                           btn
                       }
                   }
               };

               btn.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                   var url = "https://stripe.com/docs/checkout";
                   CrossShare.Current.OpenBrowser (url, new BrowserOptions {
                       ChromeShowTitle = true,
                       ChromeToolbarColor = new ShareColor {
                           A = 255,
                           R = 118,
                           G = 53,
                           B = 235
                       },
                       UseSafairReaderMode = false,
                       UseSafariWebViewController = false
                   });
               };
           }

           protected override void OnStart ()
           {
               // Handle when your app starts
           }

           protected override void OnSleep ()
           {
               // Handle when your app sleeps
           }

           protected override void OnResume ()
           {
               // Handle when your app resumes
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run the project on a device
4. Click on "Click on me!" button
5. Click on "Pay with Card" button on the Webview

[image: Filling Form] ↝ [image: Checking out]